# Access to email signatures

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I haven't really been able to find anything in the documentation and the stuff on Google is about 2-3 years old, and so this is the simple question:
**Is there a way to update somebody's email signature with the Outlook REST API?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're seeing 2yr old docs, you're looking at the wrong documentation. Graph's official documentation can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview). This documentation is open source and against on GitHub: [microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs).

As to email signatures, I'm afraid this isn't available via Graph. Email signatures are stored by the Outlook client, not within the mailbox. This is why users see different signatures across desktop, mobile, and web clients.

The only settings like this available via Graph are settings stored at the mailbox level. These are accessed via [mailboxSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0) object: `automaticRepliesSetting`, `language`, `timeZone`, and `workingHours`.